# I want to extract the absent with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table:

```
id  id_emp  ch_in  type     date
======================================
1     1     09:12  attend   2019-08-04
2     1     NULL   absent   2019-08-04
3     2     09:20  attend   2019-08-04
4     2     NULL   absent   2019-08-04
5     3     NULL   absent   2019-08-04
6     1     NULL   absent   2019-08-05
```

I want to select all absent employee ids (`id_emp`). However, if the employee already has an earlier `ch_in` that's not null in the same date he is not absent.

So in the sample data, the results would be:

the result must be:

```
id  id_emp  ch_in  type     date
======================================
5    3      NULL   absent   2019-08-04
6    1      NULL   absent   2019-08-05
```

I tired to do this:

```
select distinct id_emp,ch_in,type,date  
FROM ch_inout 
where   absent= 'absent'
```

But I can't make it work. How can I get the correct results?

Comment: Add `CH_IN IS NULL` in the `Where` condition

Comment: @WEI_DBA That won't be enough.

Comment: How can someone be attending and absent on the same date?

Comment: Why did you try `where absent='absent'`?   You don't have a column named `absent` in the sample table you posted.

Comment: Because i collect the data from 2 device attendance and want to treat the data like this

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, Yes you are right. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With NOT EXISTS:

```
select c.* from ch_inout c
where c.type = 'absent'
and not exists (
  select 1 from ch_inout
  where id_emp = c.id_emp and date = c.date and ch_in is not null
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e67385cece8f09e1c90ee1fc3cdf2fbe).
Results:

```
> id | id_emp | ch_in | type   | date               
> -: | -----: | :---- | :----- | :---------
>  5 |      3 | null  | absent | 04/08/2019
>  6 |      1 | null  | absent | 05/08/2019
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT id_emp, date
FROM ch_inout 
GROUP BY id_emp, date
HAVING MAX(ch_in) IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for trying but it get 1 row must be 2 rows in above

Comment: @programmer_25 Run that exact code on that exact sample data and you'll get two rows.You missed something translating this back from the question sample to your real data.

Comment: @programmer_25 . . .  It is unclear from the phrasing of the question if the employee needs to be explicitly "absent".  However, this should do what you want.

Comment: @programmer_25 Here's the proof: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tA4zkP4Bd6m1Ek2cXYJG8Z/0